# Google Custom Search not indexing Dynamic Pages

Tags: search

I am trying to use Google Custom Search to provide search capabilities to an informational site.

**About the site:**

- Content is generated dynamically
- URL Access to content is search engine friendly (i.e. site.com/Info/3/4/45)
- Sitemap (based on RSS feed) submitted
  and accepted by web master tools. It
  notes that no pages were indexed.
- Annotations sucessfully submitted based on the RSS feed

**Problem:**

There are no results for any keywords that appear on the pages that were submitted.

**Questions:**

- Why is Google not indexing the submitted pages?
- What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you wait for a few days to a week before coming to the conclusion (problem)?

Comment: I've waited a few months. I expected that it would take some time for their crawler to get to it, but not this long.

Comment: Hi, I reread your question. You did mention about your page using Google Custom Search. Is your 'dynamic page' is really the page with the result from the search from Google Custom Search. If it is, it is very likely that Google bot recognize this as such, and it excludes it at all from indexing. I am not saying that you did this, but bear in mind that some black hat SEO may got us penalized by the crawler. In addition of that, did you submission tool by Google or some other third party submission tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Search with basic settings is principally same thing as standard search with `site:your.website`. Does standard search give you expected results?

Note, that Google doesn't index pages immediately. It takes some time. [Check if your site is already indexed.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35256)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it took about 2 weeks for Google to pick up all my pages after I submitted a site map. But you should see a few pages indexed after a couple days.

Comment: Can you point me to where the format of the sitemap is described in the Doc. I can't seem to find it yet.