# Google Custom Search - Static Pages to WordPress (Dynamic)

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm gearing up to launch a site that has been entirely converted from static pages to WordPress as the CMS. The static site uses Google to search the site and I was wondering how do I go about having Google index the dynamic pages/posts that were/are created? Do I just have to make the site live and wait for Google to crawl it? Thanks in advance!

BTW: I checked this answer out [Google Custom Search not indexing Dynamic Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840706/google-custom-search-not-indexing-dynamic-pages) and it didn't quite answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you just have to simply wait it out. It took about 2 - 3 weeks for everything to be crawled.